# Difference between luminance and brightness

Tags: terminology

What is the difference between Luminance and Brigthness? If there is any...

Comment: Luminance is the scientific measure of how bright something is.  Just like asking "what is the difference between fahrenheit and hotness."

Comment: Are you referring to a specific context, like sliders in a piece of software, or just the terms in general?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the comment on the question by Patrick Hughes:

> Luminance is the scientific measure of how bright something is. Just like asking "what is the difference between fahrenheit and hotness."